# Hashicorp Vault - read failed: decryption failed: cipher: message authentication failed

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Having just installed Vault I am now trying to understand how it works.

I am using postman to try to get a secret from Vault.  I created a new secret called Test in cubbyhole and accessed it by using a get to:

```
https://myVault/v1/cubbyhole/Test
```

and I get the secret back correctly.

I then added a new KV (v1) secrets engine called Apps and created a secret called Test in it and tried to access it using:

```
 https://myVault/v1/Apps/Test/
```

where I get the response:

**{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* read failed: decryption failed: cipher: message authentication failed\n\n"]}**

I am connecting using the root token and I can see the secret in the UI.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last forward slash from the URL: https://myVault/v1/Apps/Test/ to change it to https://myVault/v1/Apps/Test